# TikZ, passing two values as an ordered pair

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to pass two values to a pic code as a single ordered pair. The two values are not related in any way to the coordinate system, so I expect to get the same values whatever the unit vectors directions are. I read about the `tikz@scan@one@point` command that is nearly what I'm searching for, but it returns two dimensions which depend on the coordinate system. See the following example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  options/.code={
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\valA}{\the\pgf@x/1cm}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\valB}{\the\pgf@y/1cm}%
  },
  test/.pic={
    \node {(\valA,\valB)};
    \draw circle (1);
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tikz\pic [options={(2,3)}] {test};
\tikz\pic [x=2cm, options={(2,3)}] {test};
\end{document}
```

[image]

I could divide these values by the two unit vector lengths, but I'd rather prevent any rounding errors. So I thought of temporarily replacing the coordinate system with the default one by means of the command `\tikzset{x=1cm, y=1cm}`, but I cannot do it locally, because the new units are passed to the code in the pic too. See the following example where the circle on the right should be an ellipse:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  options/.code={
    \tikzset{x=1cm, y=1cm}
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\valA}{\the\pgf@x/1cm}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\valB}{\the\pgf@y/1cm}%
  },
  test/.pic={
    \node {(\valA,\valB)};
    \draw circle (1);
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tikz\pic [options={(2,3)}] {test};
\tikz\pic [x=2cm, options={(2,3)}] {test};
\end{document}
```

[image]

So the question is: how can I pass two values as an ordered pair independent from the coordinate system, preventing rounding errors and picture deformation?

Comment: Why not `key/.store in` ? Or get/set value ?

Comment: Because the value is an ordered couple of values, not just a single value and I want to work with the two values separately elsewhere.

Comment: It can also separate and store them in different keys.

Comment: Does `options/.code args={(#1,#2)}{\def\valA{#1}\def\valB{#2}}` not do what is required?`

Comment: @MarkWibrow, this is exactly what I was looking for. Please write down your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use the `code args` handler:

```
options/.code args={(#1,#2)}{\def\valA{#1}\def\valB{#2}}
```

For more details, see section 82.4 ("Key Handlers") and specifically section 82.4.3 ("Defining Key Codes") in the manual for the latest PGF release.